# Installing Heroku Toolbelt on Ubuntu through a proxy

Tags: ubuntu, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to install the Heroku Toolbelt on an Ubuntu machine that's connected to the internet through a proxy. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and its settings but I managed to get connected to the internet fine. Internet seems to be working fine for just browsing and getting updates via apt-get is always successful and curl commands return what's expected.

When I try to run the command on the Heroku Toolbelt site:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

I get some errors:

```
me@mypc-vb:~/Documents/stuff$ wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
[sudo] password for hsiehbe: 
--2012-11-15 15:09:46--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `toolbelt.heroku.com'
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease           
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                       
...
Fetched 12.9 MB in 32s (394 kB/s)                                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1 graphviz ruby1.9.1-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,815 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

The most noticeable error is probably just

```
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com... failed: Name or service not know.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same problem when installing heroku toolbelt behind proxy:

The core of the problem is this:

```
GPG error: http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release: The following
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
```

You will notice, that the next time that you run apt-get update you will obtain the same message. It seems that ubuntu is not able to aquire the public key of heroku package repository.

To get over this you can attach the public key manually as described here:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  C927EBE00F1B0520 
gpg -a --export C927EBE00F1B0520 | sudo apt-key add -
```

After this the installation script will run OK.

Comment: Please note that the second code block is actually two separate commands, and you need to swap out both "C927EBE00F1B0520" with the error you actually get

Comment: I wasn't able to get heroku key at pgpkeys.mit.edu resulting in "no valid OpenPGP data found" error message when running the `gpg` command. I got the key from heroku ` wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key` and then `sudo apt-key add release.key` to add the key. The install script ran fine then.

Comment: @McOda Thaks ... i added release key and it's working